# Parent() isn't Working... Don't Know How to Select That Element!

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent

There are a lot of `div.post`. I need to select one of them... that one that have `$(.comment_this').attr('rel')`. And then add new tag in `<!-- Here! -->` place. Any idea?

FireBug says that parent() isn't a function... jQuery 1.6.1.

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="post_head"><div>&nbsp;</div></div>
    <div class="post_body">
        <!-- ... -->
        <div class="options">
                <a class="gray_button comment_this" href="#" rel="123">Comments</a>
                <span class="gray_txt">0 comments</span>
        </div>
        <!-- Here! -->
    </div>
    <div class="post_bottom"><div>&nbsp;</div></div>
</div>
```

This is what I have...

```
$('.post .comment_this').attr('rel').parent().html('foo');
```

Comment: I posted as answer but it's better to comment instead, as Im not sure about it. Isn't .attr() breaking chaining so you're calling parent() on a string?

Comment: @stecb looks right to me, post an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select an element that has an attribute, use the [has-attribute selector `[name]`](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector). [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) returns the value of the attribute, rather than filtering by it. Obviously strings (such as `"123"`) don't have a `parent` method!

You probably also need [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after), rather than [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html), so that you don't overwrite wanted content.

```
$('.comment_this[rel]').parent().after('your html');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.comment_this[rel] ').parent().after('foo');
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3kVr/)